# Interior angle of the triangle

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking at the following exercise:

A sailor circumnavigates Australia by a route consisting of a triangle whose sides are arcs of great circles.

Prove that at least one interior angle of the triangle is $\geq \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{10}{169}$ radians.

(Take the Earth to be a sphere of radius $6,500$km and assume that the area of Australia is $7.5$ million square kilometres.)

$$$$

Could you give me a hint what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Hint: The area of a spherical triangle drawn on a sphere of radius $R$ is $R^2(A+B+C-\pi)$, where $A, B, C$ are the angles.  The expression $A+B+C-\pi$ is usually called the *spherical excess.*

Comment: Is the area equal to $7500000$ ? So do we have $$7500000=6500^2(A+B+C-\pi)$$ ? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Yes. Divide and do some cancellation. You will get $A+B+C-\pi=\frac{30}{169}$, and now it's almost over.

Comment: To get the desired result we suppose that $A=B=C$, or not? @AndréNicolas

Comment: If you want. I would prefer to say that the sum of the angles is greater than $\pi +30/169$, so at least one of the angles must be greater than $1/3$ of that, which is $\pi/3+10/169$.

Comment: Why is the sum of the angles greater than $\pi+\frac{30}{169}$ ? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Because from area of Australia big we got $A+B+C-\pi\gt 30/169$, so by manipulation $A+B+C\gt \pi+30/169$.

Comment: Do we use the symbol "$>$" and not the equality because the radius is the one of the Earth and not just of Australia? @AndréNicolas

Comment: I really should have used $\ge$. I used $\gt$ because I know Australia is not a spherical triangle.

Comment: I mean if we use the inequality $\geq$ and not the equality $=$, because the radius is the one of the Earth and not just of Australia. Or is there an other reason? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Nothing to do with the radius of the Earth. If Australia was a spherical triangle, we would have $A+B+C-\pi=30/169$. If moreover it was an equiangular spherical triangle, we would have all angles equal to $\pi.3+10/169$.

Comment: Since Australia is not a spherical triangle, but smaller, we have that $$\text{Area of Australia}\leq R^2(A+B+C-\pi) \\ \Rightarrow 7500000\leq 6500^2(A+B+C-\pi) \\ \Rightarrow A+B+C-\pi\geq \frac{30}{169} \\ \Rightarrow A+B+C\geq \pi+\frac{30}{169} $$ Is this correct? But how do we conclude that at least one of the angles must be greater than $\frac{1}{3}$ of that? I got stuck right now... @AndréNicolas

Comment: We prove $\ge$ since that's all we are asked to do. If all the angles were less than $\pi/3+10/169$. their sum would be less than $\pi+30/160$. But it is not less than $\pi+30/169$. Same argument as if the sum of the weights of $3$ kids is $\ge 96$ then at least one of the kids has weight $\ge 32$.

Comment: @MaryStar - your solution is correct, with AndréNicolas's final step.  You should write up your own answer and accept it :-)

Comment: I got it!! Thank you so much!! :-) @AndréNicolas

Comment: Ok!! Thanks!! :-) @Frentos

Comment: Why do we know that Australia is not a spherical triangle? @AndréNicolas

Comment: As I pointed out, this is irrelevant to the $\ge$ question, and I am sorry I mentioned it. Look at a globe. The coast line of Australia has indentations. Not to mention Tasmania.